# Less filament from the half to the end

Tags: print-quality, filament, slic3r

since some prints my printer (Geeetech i3) prints less and less filament over time:

[image: less plastic]

Notice, that the beginning is printed well:

[image]

**My settings for this print (Slic3r):**

```
; avoid_crossing_perimeters = 0
; bed_shape = 0x0,200x0,200x200,0x200
; bed_temperature = 60
; before_layer_gcode = 
; between_objects_gcode = 
; bridge_acceleration = 0
; bridge_fan_speed = 100
; brim_connections_width = 0
; brim_width = 0
; complete_objects = 0
; cooling = 1
; default_acceleration = 0
; disable_fan_first_layers = 3
; duplicate_distance = 6
; end_filament_gcode = "; Filament-specific end gcode \n;END gcode for filament\n"
; end_gcode = M104 S0 ; turn off temperature\nG28 X0  ; home X axis\nM84     ; disable motors\n
; extruder_clearance_height = 20
; extruder_clearance_radius = 20
; extruder_offset = 0x0
; extrusion_axis = E
; extrusion_multiplier = 1
; fan_always_on = 0
; fan_below_layer_time = 60
; filament_colour = #FFFFFF
; filament_cost = 19.99
; filament_density = 0.945
; filament_diameter = 1.75
; filament_max_volumetric_speed = 0
; filament_notes = ""
; first_layer_acceleration = 0
; first_layer_bed_temperature = 60
; first_layer_extrusion_width = 0.4
; first_layer_speed = 30
; first_layer_temperature = 220
; gcode_arcs = 0
; gcode_comments = 0
; gcode_flavor = reprap
; has_heatbed = 1
; infill_acceleration = 0
; infill_first = 0
; interior_brim_width = 0
; layer_gcode = 
; max_fan_speed = 100
; max_layer_height = 0.4
; max_print_speed = 80
; max_volumetric_speed = 0
; min_fan_speed = 35
; min_layer_height = 0.15
; min_print_speed = 10
; min_skirt_length = 0
; notes = 
; nozzle_diameter = 0.4
; only_retract_when_crossing_perimeters = 1
; ooze_prevention = 0
; output_filename_format = [input_filename_base].gcode
; perimeter_acceleration = 0
; post_process = 
; pressure_advance = 0
; printer_notes = 
; resolution = 0
; retract_before_travel = 2
; retract_layer_change = 0
; retract_length = 2
; retract_length_toolchange = 10
; retract_lift = 0
; retract_lift_above = 0
; retract_lift_below = 0
; retract_restart_extra = 0
; retract_restart_extra_toolchange = 0
; retract_speed = 40
; skirt_distance = 5
; skirt_height = 1
; skirts = 2
; slowdown_below_layer_time = 5
; spiral_vase = 0
; standby_temperature_delta = -5
; start_filament_gcode = "; Filament gcode\n"
; start_gcode = G28 ; home all axes\nG1 Z5 F5000 ; lift nozzle\n
; temperature = 220
; threads = 4
; toolchange_gcode = 
; travel_speed = 120
; use_firmware_retraction = 0
; use_relative_e_distances = 0
; use_set_and_wait_bed = 0
; use_set_and_wait_extruder = 0
; use_volumetric_e = 0
; vibration_limit = 0
; wipe = 0
; z_offset = 0
; z_steps_per_mm = 0
; adaptive_slicing = 0
; adaptive_slicing_quality = 75%
; dont_support_bridges = 0
; extrusion_width = 0.4
; first_layer_height = 0.2
; infill_only_where_needed = 0
; interface_shells = 0
; layer_height = 0.15
; match_horizontal_surfaces = 0
; raft_layers = 0
; regions_overlap = 0
; seam_position = aligned
; sequential_print_priority = 0
; support_material = 0
; support_material_angle = 0
; support_material_buildplate_only = 0
; support_material_contact_distance = 0.2
; support_material_enforce_layers = 0
; support_material_extruder = 1
; support_material_extrusion_width = 0.4
; support_material_interface_extruder = 1
; support_material_interface_extrusion_width = 0.4
; support_material_interface_layers = 3
; support_material_interface_spacing = 0
; support_material_interface_speed = 100%
; support_material_max_layers = 0
; support_material_pattern = pillars
; support_material_spacing = 2.5
; support_material_speed = 60
; support_material_threshold = 60%
; xy_size_compensation = 0
; bottom_infill_pattern = rectilinear
; bottom_solid_layers = 3
; bridge_flow_ratio = 1
; bridge_speed = 60
; external_perimeter_extrusion_width = 0.6
; external_perimeter_speed = 50%
; external_perimeters_first = 0
; extra_perimeters = 1
; fill_angle = 45
; fill_density = 25%
; fill_gaps = 1
; fill_pattern = honeycomb
; gap_fill_speed = 20
; infill_every_layers = 1
; infill_extruder = 1
; infill_extrusion_width = 0.4
; infill_overlap = 55%
; infill_speed = 80
; overhangs = 1
; perimeter_extruder = 1
; perimeter_extrusion_width = 0.4
; perimeter_speed = 60
; perimeters = 1
; small_perimeter_speed = 15
; solid_infill_below_area = 5
; solid_infill_every_layers = 0
; solid_infill_extruder = 1
; solid_infill_extrusion_width = 0.4
; solid_infill_speed = 30
; thin_walls = 1
; top_infill_extrusion_width = 0.4
; top_infill_pattern = rectilinear
; top_solid_infill_speed = 15
; top_solid_layers = 3
```

I've tried other filaments (PLA) and higher temperatures (190-240). I also cleaned the nozzle.

What is this problem called and how to fix it?

Comment: Hi, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE!

Answer (score 2):

Your filament diameter in the slicer is okay, so big chance this is caused by something different:

- heat creep, or
- a mechanical issue of the extruder; e.g. grub screw is loose, too less tension on the extruder roller, etc. or
- lots of friction on the spool can also cause this, or
- your nozzle is partly clogged and requires a thorough cleaning of the nozzle assembly.

The search term you're looking for is "under extrusion".

Comment: I checked the plastic spool and it is not much filament left. Maybe this is the reason? I tried a not unpacked role with new plastic: it works better. I there a way to "clean" filament? Maybe it is to dusty or to old?

Comment: @Jonas For 2.85 mm filament this can be an issue, for 1.75 mm that is usually not a problem. But the smaller the diameter of unrolling the higher the extruder needs to pull to turn the spool around. Could be too much friction. I've printed kilometers of filament, but never had problems with dust. Thingiverse.com is full of cleaners but I'm skeptical to those things. Cleaning the extruder once in a while might not be a bad idea, I do that regularly.

Comment: It could be that the curl of the filament close to the spindle is causing friction through the delivery tubing - especially if a new spool does not have this problem, and that's all that you changed.